# Webview contents not visible completely without scroll in ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a multiple webview on a horizontal scrollview, in this each webview each page will be loading. The issue is webpage not fixed into a frame ( My frame size is 768 * 1024 ). I have used

```
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

but this is not fixed my problem.

```
    [webView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

When i add this code the bottom part of webview not visible but when i remove this my content visible in vertical scroll. But when i double tap on webview it gives correct view (Refer Image 2 ) I have tried my Java scripts answered here but it is not worked on my scenario. How to fix this case?  I attached my screenshot with this.

This is the look which now i have
[image: This is the look which now i have]
     This is the look actually i want
[image: This is the look actually i want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I put this code, now it comes well.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView{

    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.scrollTop = 50" ]];
}
```